# Meaning of the statement "I got my"

Tags: differences, get-passive

Does anybody know the difference between these two statements?

1. My hands got stuck in the drain.
2. I got my hands stuck in the drain.

Comment: You mean your hands got stuck down or in the drain. A sink cannot cause your hands to get stuck. Sinks are made to accommodate hands.

Comment: Hi Lambie, I meant Sink drain

Comment: I changed it. Both are grammatical, there is no difference in meaning, though there might be -- in some circumstances -- some responsibility expressed by (2). The _get_ passive often involves that, as in _He was arrested/He got arrested/He got himself arrested_, which go from neutral to responsible.

Comment: There is no difference in meaning, although a prescriptivist might complain about the word choice of "got" in both sentences.

Comment: useful information: one of the meanings of **get** is **become,**,which could be used in 1) but not in 2).

Answer (score 1):

> My hands got stuck in the drain

makes *hands* the subject of the sentence. Who caused my hands to be stuck in the drain? This is not specified in the sentence above.

> I got my hands stuck in the drain

Makes *hands* the object of the sentence and thus clearly describes the person responsible for this.

The construction of the sentence allows the speaker to omit certain information. For example, imagine the example of

> The project was ruined

vs.

> I ruined the project

I don't want to take blame for ruining the project, so I am purposely ambiguous in my phrasing.